# 'Operation not permitted' when using modprobe/insmod

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I'm trying to install a driver module for a dedicated PCIe board. I'm using the same OS and kernel versions stated in the datasheet but am getting the `Operation not permitted` error when adding the module to the kernel.

Things I've tried:

1. Disabling Secure Boot and other Bios options that might interfere. I've also used `mokutil --sb-stat` which returns `SecureBoot disabled`.
2. Signing the module and using MOK management during boot (as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur/768310#768310)).
3. Running modprobe/insmod as root.
4. `lsmod` to check if module was already added somehow, which it isn't.

Edit: The `sudo modprobe -vvv` output is as follows:

```
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:365 kmod_set_log_fn() custom logging function 0x559b6c01fc70 registered
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/modules.dep.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/modules.alias.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/modules.symbols.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/modules.builtin.alias.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/modules.builtin.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:556 kmod_module_new_from_lookup() input alias=CsE16bcd, normalized=CsE16bcd
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:562 kmod_module_new_from_lookup() lookup modules.dep CsE16bcd
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:598 kmod_search_moddep() use mmaped index 'modules.dep' modname=CsE16bcd
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:403 kmod_pool_get_module() get module name='CsE16bcd' found=(nil)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:411 kmod_pool_add_module() add 0x559b6d4f1d50 key='CsE16bcd'
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:202 kmod_module_parse_depline() 0 dependencies for CsE16bcd
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:589 kmod_module_new_from_lookup() lookup CsE16bcd=0, list=0x559b6d4f9410
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:500 lookup_builtin_file() use mmaped index 'modules.builtin' modname=CsE16bcd
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1760 kmod_module_get_initstate() could not open '/sys/module/CsE16bcd/initstate': No such file or directory
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1770 kmod_module_get_initstate() could not open '/sys/module/CsE16bcd': No such file or directory
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_pcsp mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=cx88_alsa mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_atiixp_modem mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_intel8x0m mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_via82xx_modem mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=bt87x mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=cx88_alsa mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=saa7134_alsa mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_atiixp_modem mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_intel8x0m mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_via82xx_modem mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_caiaq mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_ua101 mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_us122l mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_usx2y mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_cmipci mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_pcsp mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=bonding mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=dummy mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1404 kmod_module_get_options() modname=vt mod->name=CsE16bcd mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1760 kmod_module_get_initstate() could not open '/sys/module/CsE16bcd/initstate': No such file or directory
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1770 kmod_module_get_initstate() could not open '/sys/module/CsE16bcd': No such file or directory
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:750 kmod_module_get_path() name='CsE16bcd' path='/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/CsE16bcd.ko'
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:750 kmod_module_get_path() name='CsE16bcd' path='/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/CsE16bcd.ko'
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/CsE16bcd.ko 
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:750 kmod_module_get_path() name='CsE16bcd' path='/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/CsE16bcd.ko'
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:892 kmod_module_insert_module() Failed to insert module '/lib/modules/5.13.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/CsE16bcd.ko': Operation not permitted
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'CsE16bcd': Operation not permitted
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:468 kmod_module_unref() kmod_module 0x559b6d4f1d50 released
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:419 kmod_pool_del_module() del 0x559b6d4f1d50 key='CsE16bcd'
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:332 kmod_unref() context 0x559b6d4f14e0 released`
```

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Do any messages appear in `dmesg` after a failed load?

Comment: @Torin Nothing helpful, just `GageDrv module initialization failed, error -1`

Answer (score 0):

The `Operation not permitted` is from the kernel during the `insmod` operation. Given that the kernel ring buffer outputs `GageDrv module initialization failed, error -1`, it's likely the error is from the kernel module initialisation function and therefore the module failed to load.

The message `Operation not permitted` is likely misleading here, the driver returned -1 (`-EPERM`) which is often an overly generic error return code.

There isn't more information to go on from the question to explain why the module failed to initialise, you would need to ask the author of the `CsE16bcd` for support.